# VLC crashes on startup: Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

Tags: vlc, 20.10

I using Ubuntu 20.10. All of a sudden, VLC cannot be started. When trying to run it through the command line, I get:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.12.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.12.1-0-g170157402b)
[00005573fa81cb40] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [40 200)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I have the same issue (Ubuntu 20.10 installed from scratch) with VLC installed from snap. I tried to install apt package and it works well

Comment: I just ran into this with snap installed vlc under 21.04

Comment: Experienced this issue as well on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Curiously, my font manager is also crashing.

Comment: I am also experiencing this behavior on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with VLC installed from snap.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/keshavbhatt/olivia/issues/95#issuecomment-774747492) works for me:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```

Comment: I was able to skip the first one, and it still fixed my problem.

Comment: This worked for me and vlc started again on 23.04

Comment: Same as @DonKirkby, on Xubuntu 23.10, with VLC installed from Snap.

Comment: this is the second time this has worked for me on ubuntu 23.10  great

Answer (score 9):

VLC works well with the `apt` package, contrary to the `snap` package.

Comment: why tho? doesn't this mean something is broken with either VLC or snap?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Konqueror.

I ran ps -aux | grep konqueror
and killed the process
then konqueror ran without issues
Thank you for posting regards Michael

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/26985) works for me:

> before running vlc removes the network message. But it still does not start.

```shell
vlc -v
```

Answer (score 0):

> uninstall vlc first then install it again with

```
sudo apt-get install vlc -y

sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with another program. For me it was due to a restriction by the router: Ubuntu was connected to a FritzBox as guest and the FritzBox seems that was blocking this connection.

As soon as I changed to a normal connection, the problem was solved!