# Some apps crash before opening on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, ram, vlc, crash

For example, if I try to open a video with VLC, I can see it appear on the System monitor but it's quickly listed with red and disappears.

It could be RAM related. I have 4GB and it's shown as 70% used. But I have a 4GB swap file and it's not even 1/4 used.

I'm new to Linux.

**EDIT: Terminal message**

> 2023/06/05 17:30:51.401887 system_key.go:129: cannot determine nfs
> usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: cannot parse
> check pass number: "1o"
>
> VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d)
> [00005569c51d7460] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default
> interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
>
> Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
>
> Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [40
> 200) Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: HI. Try to open VLC using the terminal. 
- Open the terminal application
- write there 'vlc' and press enter

It will crash but  will leave you some text that you can add to the question

Comment: @aafirvida
I added the info to the main post

Comment: @fede - if vlc was installed as snap - remove it and install it via apt. It should work then, (First thing I do on Ubuntu is to remove snap and all related packages)

Comment: @kanehekili +1 to your comment, I do the same. Snap does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for this same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311408/vlc-crashes-on-startup-qt-session-management-error-could-not-open-network-soc)

You can solve your vlc problem with:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/* 
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```