# VLC and MPV cannot play video files from samba share

Tags: 22.04, video, samba, vlc, mpv-media-player

This involves a [Freebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebox) [Pop](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Freebox_Pop_Server_V8.jpg) server but (see NOTE at the end) is not limited to the Freebox server, as all samba shares are affected. The Freebox has a USB entry where I have put an external 2 GB drive containing mostly videos that I can thus access and play very well with an Android TV device (or with the phone etc).

But, to my surprise, on a rather old laptop running Kubuntu 22.04, while ***Dolphin can access that drive and make changes to it***, video files cannot be played by the video players I normally use - VLC and MPV.

Photos are instantly opened by Gwenview.

PDFs are opened in Okular but the file is first copied on the computer it seems.

MPV gives this error:

```
mpv 'smb://freebox-server.local/Volume 2000Go/FILME/IT_2/---a-voir/A.Mezzanotte.Va.La.Ronda.Del.Piacere.1975.mkv' 
[ffmpeg] Protocol not found. Make sure ffmpeg/Libav is compiled with networking support.
Failed to open smb://freebox-server.local/Volume 2000Go/FILME/IT_2/---a-voir/A.Mezzanotte.Va.La.Ronda.Del.Piacere.1975.mkv.

Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

That [might be ffmpeg-specific](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/mpv-cant-play-files-over-samba-share-anymore-because-of-ffmpeg/44945), but VLC is also unable to play:

```
vlc 'smb://freebox-server.local/Volume 2000Go/FILME/Les Felins_a.en-fr.mkv' 
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[00005558f566b640] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007fbf3c0016f0] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fbf3c0016f0] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fbf3c04dc30] mkv demux error: cannot find any cluster or chapter, damaged file ?
[00007fbf3c0016f0] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fbf3c04dc30] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
```

The snap version of VLC gives this:

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vlc_vlc.desktop /snap/bin/vlc
VLC media player 3.0.19 Vetinari (revision 3.0.19-0-g32b50de2a2)
[000055698c544b10] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
[000055698c5db150] main playlist: playlist is empty
Sending netbios packet to 192.168.1.255
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
netbios_ns_resolve, wrong query type received
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
```

And then, [with `-v` argument](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500597/925128):

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vlc_vlc.desktop /snap/bin/vlc -v 'smb://freebox-server.local/Volume 2000Go/FILME/Les Felins_a.en-fr.mkv' 
VLC media player 3.0.19 Vetinari (revision 3.0.19-0-g32b50de2a2)
[000055792cde9b10] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Sending netbios packet to 192.168.1.255
netbios_ns_resolve, wrong query type received
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
```

Kaffeine:

```
kaffeine 'smb://freebox-server.local/Volume 2000Go/FILME/Les Felins_a.en-fr.mkv' 
25-01-24 09:15:20.516 [Warning ] QCommandLineParser: already having an option named "h"
25-01-24 09:15:20.516 [Warning ] QCommandLineParser: already having an option named "help-all"
25-01-24 09:15:20.516 [Warning ] QCommandLineParser: already having an option named "v"
25-01-24 09:15:20.850 [Info    ] kaffeine.dvb: Using built-in dvb device manager
[00007fef1c001650] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fef1c001650] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fef1c050650] mkv demux error: cannot find any cluster or chapter, damaged file ?
[00007fef1c001650] smb stream error: read failed (Broken pipe)
[00007fef1c050650] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
[000056398694af50] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[000056398694af50] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'smb://freebox-server.local/Volume%202000Go/FILME/Les%20Felins_a.en-fr.mkv'. Check the log for details.
```

Trying with Gwenview:

```
kf.kio.widgets: Failed to check which JobView API is supported "The name org.kde.kuiserver was not provided by any .service files"
```

---

Kodi allows the Freebox share location to be added, and then starts playing video (although sometimes it freezes).

I was also pleasantly surprised to see how old ***Xine plays very easily those videos*** (instantly!).

But other players also work, like Totem (Gnome's 'Videos') and Glide, installed as flatpak.

---

Testing in a live session of Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome) the same problems are present with MPV and VLC - while the file manager (Nautilus) can access those files and the Gnome video player ('Videos', that's Totem I guess) can play the videos (after installing the needed codecs).

---

Are these problems related or should I treat them separately (MPV from VLC)?

---

**NOTES AND UPDATES:**

- `kio-fuse` is installed
- this is not limited (after more testing) to the Freeebox samba share, but to other samba shares too:
  for testing purposes I have created a samba share on my Android phone, and videos on the phone have the same problem with MPV and VLC on Kubuntu 22.04
- sharing the 'Movies' Android phone folder on FTP with Solid File Explorer, they can be played by VLC and MPV on this Kubuntu 22.04
- Beside Kodi, also SMPLayer, although using mpv as backend, can play fine the samba shared videos!
- Other mpv-based players, like Haruna and QMPlay2, don't work

Comment: Have you considered `kio-fuse`? Does the mpv-based KDE-branded `haruna` work?

Comment: @DanielT - I will add this to the question: `kio-fuse` is installed. Initially my question was of the form *"why no video player works etc except Kodi (and then Xine)"*. Now it's more like *"why all players work etc except vlc and mpv"*. Kaffeine seems based on vlc. Kodi uses mpv but works (poorly, that is slowly, but it's not made for the desktop anyway I think). --Xine is the best for this purpose - fast, no delay whatsoever, as if the share were a local file! -- It might very well be that the mpv and vlc are separate problems. I have linked to the mpv one.

Comment: @DanielT - Haruna doesn't work (tested various versions, Ubuntu repos, snap and flatpak), but oddly SMPlayer does!

Comment: That is interesting.  I've found that [DLNA](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel) is a much more pleasent experience, than kodi, plex and the like.  It will fix your mpv/vlc problems, and it will be accessible to smart tv's and mobile phones.

Comment: There's some other DLNA choices, but I found rygel the best.  An idea to eliminate sluggish or slower connectivity would be static IP's.  Eliminate DHCP from the IP assignment.  Hard IP addresses can help quite a bit.

Comment: Static IP's are for more than constant addressing, servers especially.  Static IP addresses can be reliably discovered and reached via their assigned hostnames and do not need to be tracked for changes. FTP and web servers mostly use fixed addresses. Static's ideal if your computer is a server. It gives file servers relatively faster rates.  It's an ideal choice for seamless connectivity.

Comment: @J.Cravens - I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/16fe2sy/comment/k2r2h4r/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), the cause is discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/szcfpk/comment/hy3azn1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/szcfpk/comment/hy7v5og/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) linking to [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/8731). I don't really understand it, but - quoting:

> The issue appears to be a combination of:
>
> - Using dolphin as the file browser to reach network shares
> - Dolphin only providing the smb:// url to mpv when you click on the
>   file in question
> - mpv deferring to ffmpeg for smb support to access file

Some comments blame Dolphin but I've seen this in Gnome with Nautilus too.

The solution is to remove the variable `smb` (one of the comments also recommends removing `ftp` and `ftps`) from the line `X-KDE-Protocols=` of the `.desktop` launcher of MPV (copy it from `usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit it there).

(This seems to be just a workaround - to make the players go around the buggy area, rather than a way of solving it.)

And I've discovered that the same change fixes it for VLC too. Kaffeine and Haruna were also fixed by *adding* that line (*without* `smb` etc), which was absent by default in their respective `.desktop` files..

Comment: Same solution as I first suggested.  Here, I have a lot of experience in this area, read this: https://chat.openai.com/share/cc87fa77-c6fc-4382-86f2-abce1c8dcfb2

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NWlq9bwvC60aBaLBmTxp7VTJAKT2wavP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Policy based routing and discovery services have everything to do with it, especially cross-platform. Things you never have to deal with on layer 2.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Dz7sfiCx7KUxLFwDbla9OdsgSybn-X8/view?usp=sharing  Start on page 57.